# Updating flutter application to already published native applications on store

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have already two published applications Android/IOS and I'm looking to create a flutter as a cross-platform to reduce the time of developing the same modules in the two applications.

There is an easy way to not create the flutter from scratch as the applications are working fine for me.

Can I use the same application ID(Android) and the bundle ID (IOS) as I will need to update it and not lose the downloads and application history from the apple store and the google store?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do it, make sure you used same package name and key other wise playstore showing error.

Comment: Do you know anything about the apple store? as the bundle id must be unique!

Answer (score 1):

I also had an Android App. I created a new app with Flutter using the same ID (package name). At the end I signed it with the same key and I uploaded the App on the Playstore without any problem. Everything is still there. The history and statistics.

Comment: Do you know anything about the apple store? as the bundle id must be unique!

Comment: I have no experience with the Apple Store. I use App bundle on the Google Play Store. It is the same process as with the APK.

Answer (score 0):

In your flutter application, navigate to android project's app level build and update the flutter app Application ID with your existing application id. (My be you already know it).

When you will generate the flutter app (android/ios) with the existing keys. Lets say your existing app on google play console is built with xyz.jks. Built your flutter android project with same key and publish on google play store.